# How do I access my Matter devices when I’m not at home?

Tags: smart-home, mqtt, protocols, cloud-computing, matter

How do device developers and major platform providers in the world such as Google Home, Apple, Tuya, and Aqara do to control Matter devices remotely??? Do they still use traditional IoT protocols like MQTT?

I tried searching but didn't have much information. Please help me with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they still need to use "IoT Protocols"

Communication between the vendors cloud services and a Hub (E.g. an Amazon Echo or a Google/Nest Hub) device still uses things like MQTT, it then maps this to a Matter/Zigbee/Thread message to any individual devices.